# Regex Not Matching as Expected in C#

Tags: c#, regex

I'm using the following code:

```
string tile = "a1";
Regex regex= new Regex(@"/([a-z])(\d{1,2})/i");
if (regex.Match(tile).Success) Console.WriteLine("Found a match.");
    else Console.WriteLine("No match.");
```

and the console returns "No match." The regex itself seems fine to me, but I'm probably missing something simple. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Add a few more samples on what you want matched and most importantly what you DON'T want matched. Do you simply want a letter followed by a single digit to be matched?

Comment: You might be interested in [Regex Hero](http://regexhero.net/tester/) for your .Net regex testing: . You can fiddle around with your regex and figure out for yourself what works and what doesn't.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're using some javascript regex delineators. Try:

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"([a-z])(\d{1,2})", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

Then you'll probably want to use [IsMatch()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3y21t6y4.aspx):

```
if(regex.IsMatch(tile))
{
    // ...
}
```

Comment: That explains a lot; I've been primarily working with PHP, Ruby and Javascript -- all of which use those delineators. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
string tile = "a1";
Regex regex = new Regex(@"([a-z])(\d{1,2})", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
if (regex.Match(tile).Success) Console.WriteLine("Found a match.");
    else Console.WriteLine("No match.");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"([a-z])(\d{1,2})");
```

I'm not sure why you have a leading `/` and a trailing `/i`.  Those match the characters `/` and `/i`, respectively.

Comment: He has those because they denote a regex-literal in javascript which ignores case.